# How can I convert dummy variables to factors in R?

Tags: r

In my data frame (called survey) there is one variable called "answer"

```
    answer
      1
      2
      1
      2
```

I want to convert these dummy variables to

```
     answer
       NO
       YES
       NO
       YES
```

what command should I apply to survey$answer data?

Actually what I want to do is to visualize the data with lattice

```
   barchart(as.factor(with(survey, survey$answer)))
```

The above command did result in a barchart, but I need to change the labels to "Yes" and "No" instead of "2" and "1". That's why I need to convert the dummy variables.

[image]

Comment: You should probably change your question title, given your edit...

Comment: And you don't need to say `survey$answer` if you're already saying `with(survey,...)`. That's redundant.

Comment: @Thomas, actually i want to know both answers. I mean both "how to change the dummy variables to factors" and "how to edit the barchart labels". The former question is of my primary interest. The edited part is also a question, but it is rather a minor question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `factor` function as in:

```
> answer <- c(1,2,1,2)
> answer <- factor(answer, labels=c("NO", "YES"))
[1] NO  YES NO  YES
Levels: NO YES
```

Comment: Thanks, I followed your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Metrics's answer will give you a character variable. For a factor:

```
answer <- rep(1:2,2)
answer <- as.factor(answer)
levels(answer) <- c("NO","YES")
```

Comment: I think @Jilber's approach is more common.

Answer (score 1):

For fun, here's another alternative. It doesn't bother converting to a factor, but that's also not necessary for your barplot:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(2, 50, replace = TRUE)
x
#  [1] 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2
# [33] 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2
c("NO", "YES")[x]
#  [1] "NO"  "NO"  "YES" "YES" "NO"  "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "NO" 
# [11] "NO"  "NO"  "YES" "NO"  "YES" "NO"  "YES" "YES" "NO"  "YES"
# [21] "YES" "NO"  "YES" "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "YES" "NO" 
# [31] "NO"  "YES" "NO"  "NO"  "YES" "YES" "YES" "NO"  "YES" "NO" 
# [41] "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "NO"  "NO"  "YES" "YES"
```

Here's your barplot:

```
library(lattice)
barchart(c("NO", "YES")[x])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
   answer<-ifelse(answer==1,"NO","YES")
> answer
[1] "NO"  "YES" "NO"  "YES"

> as.factor(answer)
[1] No  YES No  YES
Levels: No YES
```

Or, use `recode` from car package

```
answer<-recode(answer,"1='No';else='YES'")
> answer
[1] "No"  "YES" "No"  "YES"


  > as.factor(answer)
[1] No  YES No  YES
Levels: No YES
```