# Change TRUE and FALSE to Yes and No

Tags: r, boolean, logical-operators

I have the following R script:

```
x <- c('PE', 'MG', 'SP', 'GO', 'ES', 'PB', 'DF')
y <- c('PB', 'MG', 'SP', 'GO', 'ES', 'SE', 'DF')
z <- x == y
```

So that

```
> z
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

However, I want `z` (and other logical variables further down the script) to show "Yes" and "No" instead, so I do this recoding:

```
z <- ifelse(z == TRUE, "Yes", "No")
```

Is there any way to skip this extra step, i.e., define `z` show "Yes" instead of "TRUE" and "No" instead of "FALSE".

Of course, I could also do `z <- ifelse(x == y, "Yes", "No")`, but I'm still looking for something like a parameter inside the `options()` function I could define just once and have it work until the end of the script (or until I redefined the parameter). Couldn't find anything like it on `?options`.

Comment: This doesn't address your question, but you don't need the `==` since the variable is already of type `logical`. You can simple do `z = ifelse(z, 'Yes', 'No')`

Comment: I going to go ahead and say that the answer to your question is `ifelse(FALSE, 'Yes', 'No')`

Comment: @SeñorO, thanks for the input, I've forgotten about the trick. It's always nice to spare some code bytes.

Comment: @Dason, would you mind elaborating on your answer a bit? If I understood you correctly, setting `z <- ifelse(FALSE, 'Yes', 'No')` doesn't seem to do the trick even if I tell  `z` to compare `x` and `y` first (but even if it worked, it would kind of miss the question anyway).

Comment: A very similar question was [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445941/how-can-i-convert-dummy-variables-to-factors-in-r/18446035#18446035)

Comment: I was just being snarky and saying that I don't think you can do what you want to do.  Replace my code with what it outputs (ie "No")

Comment: Oh, right, now I see what you meant. :)

Comment: But for goodness' sake, **why?**  "TRUE" and "FALSE" are pretty well known, to say the least, across all programming languages.  Further,  "Yes" is most emphatically not the same as "TRUE" in general.  Leave logical values logical until you get to the very end, at which time if you really think your audience can't deal with "TRUE/FALSE", convert the strings at that time.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I want to change it for a few reasons which I hope you'll find reasonable: 1) Because in the end I'm going to present this data in form of tables, and "Yes/No" will make more sense to the reader when I rewrite the table header; 2) "TRUE/FALSE" is not only aesthetically unpleasing (hello, all caps!), but may also scream "sloppy work" in my portuguese-written document.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to overwrite the fact that `R` prints `TRUE` and `FALSE` for logical objects (personally I think that's good).

The closest solution to what you're looking for could be factor conversion:

```
z <- factor(x==y, labels=c("No", "Yes"))

> z
[1] No  Yes Yes Yes Yes No  Yes
Levels: No Yes
```

Comment: I guess the default TRUE/FALSE is convenient for quickly understanding the classes to which each object belongs, but it looks weird when I need to present data in form of a table, especially since my reports are not written in English.

Comment: Then making that change locally like you've done seems like a much better alternative than trying to change the output globally.

Comment: I think a main reason behind it is the fact that `logical` types are used for subsetting, etc.: `x[z]` works for type `logical` but not `factor`.

Comment: @wleoncio Are you running `R` with locale set to your language? And if all you're worried about is the language, why are you using English "yes/no" rather than  "Bəli/ Xeyr" or whatever?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I run R in English because otherwise I'll have problems with decimal separators. Even though in Brazil we use comma, the datasets I work with almost always use period (plus, I just like to use things in their native language whenever possible). In my actual problem, I use "Sim/Não" instead of "Yes/No", I just wanted to make the question more universal. ;)

Answer (score 8):

Another approach:

```
c('No', 'Yes')[z + 1]
```