# R: Rename dummy variable entries

Tags: r

I am struggeling with creating a new dummy variable from a categorical variable. The original variable were saved in as.character and had 4 categories (3 actual entries and a fourth empty option). Out of these I created a new variable with only 2 options. I would like those to be named "yes" and "no" instead of "TRUE" and "FALSE".

```
div_dummy <- Training_lowNA$div_type!=""
```

Output looks like this:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[25]  TRUE
```

and should look like this:

```
[1] yes yes no yes yes yes yes yes yes no yes no 
[13] yes yes yes no yes yes no yes no yes no yes 
[25]  no
```

I am quite sure there is an easy solution -- but do not seem able to find it myself. Thanks for the help!

Comment: oh hell, I just searched for an answer with the wrong title... thanks so much for the link to the very-usable answer by @akrun

Comment: actually I did it as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445941/how-can-i-convert-dummy-variables-to-factors-in-r/18446035#18446035